# Getting ValueError 'Parse error: saw </%s> instead of expected </%s>' while trying out pygments

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab, pygments

I am trying out pygments to generated formatted text for python code file.
I am trying sample code available on reportlab site. I wish to use it to generate pdf files with code suitably highlighted.

The code files are:

**PdfGenerator.py**

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import re
import os

exampleNameFontSize = 16
fileNameFontSize = 10
codeFontSize = 9
descriptionFontSize = 10

exampleNameFontName = 'Arial'
fileNameFontName = 'Arial'
codeFontName = 'Courier'
descriptionFontName = 'Arial'

exampleNameFontStyle = 'B'
fileNameFontStyle = 'B'
codeFontStyle = ''
descriptionFontStyle = ''

exampleNameCellHeight = 11
fileNameCellHeight = 9
codeCellHeight = 5
descriptionCellHeight = 5

def writeExampleName(pdf, exampleName):
#     pdf.set_margins(left=0, top=0)
    pdf.set_font(exampleNameFontName, exampleNameFontStyle, exampleNameFontSize)
    pdf.cell(0, exampleNameCellHeight, exampleName, 0, 2, "L")

def writeFileName(pdf, fileName):
    pdf.set_font(fileNameFontName, fileNameFontStyle, fileNameFontSize)
    pdf.cell(0, fileNameCellHeight, fileName, 0, 2, "L")

def writeCode(pdf, code):
    pdf.set_font(codeFontName, codeFontStyle, codeFontSize)
    pdf.multi_cell(0, codeCellHeight, code, 0, 2, "L")

def writeDescrition(pdf, description):
    pdf.set_font(descriptionFontName, descriptionFontStyle, descriptionFontSize)
    pdf.multi_cell(0, descriptionCellHeight, description, 0, 2, "L")


pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
# pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
# pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!')
# pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 26)
# pdf.cell(60, 0, 'Powered by FPDF.', 0, 2, 'C')

# writeExampleName(pdf, "Example Name 1")
# writeFileName(pdf, "FileName.txt")
# writeCode(pdf, "#include<stdio.h>\n#include<conio.h>")





#populate key value of summary 
info = {}
with open('list.txt') as fh:
    matchTuple = re.findall(r'(?ms)^(\d+)\.\s*(.*?(?=^\d+\.|\Z))', fh.read())
    for i in matchTuple:
        descr = i[1]
        p = re.compile('\n(\s*)',re.VERBOSE)  # @UndefinedVariable
#         descr1 = p.sub(r'\n', descr)
#         print('i:',i)
#         print('descr: ', descr)
#         print('descr1: ', descr1)
        if info.get(i[0]) is None:
            info[i[0]] = {} 
        info[i[0]]['description'] = descr

    print('info:', info)    
#     print(matchTuple[0])
#     print(type(matchTuple[0]))
#     print(matchTuple[0][0])
#     print(matchTuple.group(0))
#     print(matchTuple.group(1))
#     print(matchTuple.group(2))
#     print(matchTuple.group(3))
    #l = re.findall(r'(?ms)^\d+\.\s*(.*?)(?=^\d+\.|\Z)', fh.read())
    #for i in l:
    #    print(i)

root = "D:/Mahesh/repos/SpringExamples/src/main/java"
xmlroot = "D:/Mahesh/repos/SpringExamples/src/main/resources"
# get full path to all files recursively 
fileNames = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        fileNames.append(os.path.join(path, name))

# get max eg count
egCount = set()
for i in fileNames:
    matchTuple = re.search(r"eg(\d*)", i, flags=0)
    egCount.add((int)(matchTuple.group(1)))

    if info.get(matchTuple.group(1)) is not None:
#         if info.get(matchTuple.group(1)).get('path') is None:
        rindex = i.rindex("\\")-1
        info.get(matchTuple.group(1))['path'] = i[0:rindex+1] 
    else:
        print('Example ', i, 'is not there in description list')

# list1 = list(range(1,egCount))
# print(list1)

for i in egCount:  # list(range(1,egCount)):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(info[str(i)]['path']):
        writeExampleName(pdf, "Example " + str(i))
        writeDescrition(pdf, info[str(i)]['description'])
        writeFileName(pdf,"eg"+str(i)+".xml")

        if(os.path.exists(xmlroot + "\\eg" + str(i) + ".xml")):
            with open(xmlroot + "\\eg" + str(i) + ".xml") as xmlfh:
                writeCode(pdf, xmlfh.read())

        for file in files:
            with open(path + "\\" + file) as fh:
                writeFileName(pdf, file)
                writeCode(pdf, fh.read())
#                 print(fh.read())

#     i[0,i.rfind("\\")-1]  

print('info:', info)                

pdf.output('spring examples.pdf', 'F')
```

**tuto3.py**

```
from fpdf import FPDF

# title = '20000 Leagues Under the Seas'
title = 'THE ADVENTURES OF SHERLOCK HOLMES'

class PDF(FPDF):
    def header(self):
        # Arial bold 15
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 15)
        # Calculate width of title and position
        w = self.get_string_width(title) + 6
        self.set_x((210 - w) / 2)
        # Colors of frame, background and text
        self.set_draw_color(0, 80, 180)
        self.set_fill_color(230, 230, 0)
        self.set_text_color(220, 50, 50)
        # Thickness of frame (1 mm)
        self.set_line_width(1)
        # Title
        self.cell(w, 9, title, 1, 1, 'C', 1)
        # Line break
        self.ln(10)

    def footer(self):
        # Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        self.set_y(-15)
        # Arial italic 8
        self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        # Text color in gray
        self.set_text_color(128)
        # Page number
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()), 0, 0, 'C')

    def chapter_title(self, num, label):
        # Arial 12
        self.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
        # Background color
        self.set_fill_color(200, 220, 255)
        # Title
        self.cell(0, 6, 'Chapter %d : %s' % (num, label), 0, 1, 'L', 1)
        # Line break
        self.ln(4)

    def chapter_body(self, name):
        # Read text file
        with open(name, 'rb') as f:
            txt = f.read().decode('latin-1')
        # Times 12
        self.set_font('Times', '', 12)
        # Output justified text
        self.multi_cell(0, 5, txt)
        # Line break
        self.ln()
        # Mention in italics
        self.set_font('', 'I')
        self.cell(0, 5, '(end of excerpt)')

    def print_chapter(self, num, title, name):
        self.add_page()
        self.chapter_title(num, title)
        self.chapter_body(name)

pdf = PDF()
pdf.set_title(title)
pdf.set_author('Arthur Conan Doyle')
# pdf.print_chapter(1, 'A RUNAWAY REEF', '20k_c1.txt')
# pdf.print_chapter(2, 'THE PROS AND CONS', '20k_c2.txt')
pdf.print_chapter(1, 'Chp 1', 'sherlock.txt')
pdf.output('tuto3.pdf', 'F')
```

pygments code:

**pygments2xpre.py** ([source](https://www.reportlab.com/snippets/11/))

```
__all__ = ('pygments2xpre',)

def _2xpre(s,styles):
    "Helper to transform Pygments HTML output to ReportLab markup"
    s = s.replace('<div class="highlight">','')
    s = s.replace('</div>','')
    s = s.replace('<pre>','')
    s = s.replace('</pre>','')
    s = s.replace('</span>','</font>')
    for k,c in styles+[('p','#000000'),('n','#000000')]:
        s = s.replace('<span class="%s">' % k,'<font color="%s">' % c)
    return s

def pygments2xpre(s):
    "Return markup suitable for XPreformatted"
    try:
        from pygments import highlight
        from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
        from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
    except ImportError:
        return s

    l = PythonLexer()
    h = HtmlFormatter()

    try:
        from StringIO import StringIO
    except ImportError:
        from io import StringIO

    out = StringIO()
    highlight(s,l,h,out)
    styles = [(cls, style.split(';')[0].split(':')[1].strip())
                for cls, (style, ttype, level) in h.class2style.items()
                if cls and style and style.startswith('color:')]
    return _2xpre(out.getvalue(),styles)


def convertSourceFiles(filenames):
    "Helper function - makes minimal PDF document"

    from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Spacer, XPreformatted
    from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
    styT=getSampleStyleSheet()["Title"]
    styC=getSampleStyleSheet()["Code"]
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("pygments2xpre.pdf")
    S = [].append
    for filename in filenames:
        S(Paragraph(filename,style=styT))
        src = open(filename, 'r').read()
        fmt = pygments2xpre(src)
        S(XPreformatted(fmt, style=styC))
    doc.build(S.__self__)
    print('saved pygments2xpre.pdf')

convertSourceFiles(['tuto3.py','PdfGenerator.py'])
```

I am getting following error:

```
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\python.exe" "D:\Programs\Eclipse Neon\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 20012)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Eclipse Neon\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1655, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Programs\Eclipse Neon\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1649, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "D:\Programs\Eclipse Neon\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1055, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:\Programs\Eclipse Neon\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.3.201805051638\pysrc\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:\workspaces\workspace6\PdfGenerator\pygments2xpre.py", line 72, in <module>
    convertSourceFiles(['tuto3.py','PdfGenerator.py'])
  File "D:\workspaces\workspace6\PdfGenerator\pygments2xpre.py", line 60, in convertSourceFiles
    S(XPreformatted(fmt, style=styC))
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\xpreformatted.py", line 81, in __init__
    self._setup(text, style, bulletText, frags, cleaner)
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\paragraph.py", line 1551, in _setup
    style, frags, bulletTextFrags = _parser.parse(text,style)
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\paraparser.py", line 3217, in parse
    annotateException('\nparagraph text %s caused exception' % ascii(text))
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 1406, in annotateException
    rl_reraise(t,v,b)
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 144, in rl_reraise
    raise v
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\paraparser.py", line 3215, in parse
    self.feed(text)
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\html\parser.py", line 111, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\html\parser.py", line 173, in goahead
    k = self.parse_endtag(i)
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\html\parser.py", line 421, in parse_endtag
    self.handle_endtag(elem.lower())
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\paraparser.py", line 3251, in handle_endtag
    end()
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\paraparser.py", line 2833, in end_font
    self._pop('font')
  File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\paraparser.py", line 3064, in _pop
    raise ValueError('Parse error: saw </%s> instead of expected </%s>' % (tag,frag.__tag__))
ValueError: Parse error: saw </font> instead of expected </span>
paragraph text '<para><span></font><font color="#008000">from</font> <font color="#0000FF">fpdf</font> <font color="#008000">import</font> <font color="#000000">FPDF</font>\n\n<font color="#408080"># title = &#39;20000 Leagues Under the Seas&#39;</font>\n<font color="#000000">title</font> <font color="#666666">=</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;THE ADVENTURES OF SHERLOCK HOLMES&#39;</font>\n\n<font color="#008000">class</font> <font color="#0000FF">PDF</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">FPDF</font><font color="#000000">):</font>\n    <font color="#008000">def</font> <font color="#0000FF">header</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#000000">):</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Arial bold 15</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_font</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;Arial&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;B&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">15</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Calculate width of title and position</font>\n        <font color="#000000">w</font> <font color="#666666">=</font> <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">get_string_width</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">title</font><font color="#000000">)</font> <font color="#666666">+</font> <font color="#666666">6</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_x</font><font color="#000000">((</font><font color="#666666">210</font> <font color="#666666">-</font> <font color="#000000">w</font><font color="#000000">)</font> <font color="#666666">/</font> <font color="#666666">2</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Colors of frame, background and text</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_draw_color</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">80</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">180</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_fill_color</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">230</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">230</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_text_color</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">220</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">50</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">50</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Thickness of frame (1 mm)</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_line_width</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">1</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Title</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">cell</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">w</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">9</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">title</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">1</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">1</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;C&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">1</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Line break</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">ln</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">10</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n\n    <font color="#008000">def</font> <font color="#0000FF">footer</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#000000">):</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Position at 1.5 cm from bottom</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_y</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">-</font><font color="#666666">15</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Arial italic 8</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_font</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;Arial&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;I&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">8</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Text color in gray</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_text_color</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">128</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Page number</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">cell</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">10</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;Page &#39;</font> <font color="#666666">+</font> <font color="#008000">str</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">page_no</font><font color="#000000">()),</font> <font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;C&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n\n    <font color="#008000">def</font> <font color="#0000FF">chapter_title</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">num</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">label</font><font color="#000000">):</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Arial 12</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_font</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;Arial&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">12</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Background color</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_fill_color</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">200</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">220</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">255</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Title</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">cell</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">6</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;Chapter </font><font color="#BB6688">%d</font><font color="#BA2121"> : </font><font color="#BB6688">%s</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;</font> <font color="#666666">%</font> <font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">num</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">label</font><font color="#000000">),</font> <font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">1</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;L&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">1</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Line break</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">ln</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">4</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n\n    <font color="#008000">def</font> <font color="#0000FF">chapter_body</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">name</font><font color="#000000">):</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Read text file</font>\n        <font color="#008000">with</font> <font color="#008000">open</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">name</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;rb&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font> <font color="#008000">as</font> <font color="#000000">f</font><font color="#000000">:</font>\n            <font color="#000000">txt</font> <font color="#666666">=</font> <font color="#000000">f</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">read</font><font color="#000000">()</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">decode</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;latin-1&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Times 12</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_font</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;Times&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">12</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Output justified text</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">multi_cell</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">5</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">txt</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Line break</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">ln</font><font color="#000000">()</font>\n        <font color="#408080"># Mention in italics</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_font</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;I&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">cell</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">0</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#666666">5</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;(end of excerpt)&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n\n    <font color="#008000">def</font> <font color="#0000FF">print_chapter</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">num</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">title</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">name</font><font color="#000000">):</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">add_page</font><font color="#000000">()</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">chapter_title</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">num</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#000000">title</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n        <font color="#008000">self</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">chapter_body</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">name</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n\n<font color="#000000">pdf</font> <font color="#666666">=</font> <font color="#000000">PDF</font><font color="#000000">()</font>\n<font color="#000000">pdf</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_title</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#000000">title</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n<font color="#000000">pdf</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">set_author</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;Arthur Conan Doyle&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n<font color="#408080"># pdf.print_chapter(1, &#39;A RUNAWAY REEF&#39;, &#39;20k_c1.txt&#39;)</font>\n<font color="#408080"># pdf.print_chapter(2, &#39;THE PROS AND CONS&#39;, &#39;20k_c2.txt&#39;)</font>\n<font color="#000000">pdf</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">print_chapter</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#666666">1</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;Chp 1&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;sherlock.txt&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font>\n<font color="#000000">pdf</font><font color="#666666">.</font><font color="#000000">output</font><font color="#000000">(</font><font color="#BA2121">&#39;tuto3.pdf&#39;</font><font color="#000000">,</font> <font color="#BA2121">&#39;F&#39;</font><font color="#000000">)</font></para>' caused exception
```

Why is it so? Does the pygments lexers and html formatter generating wrong output?

Comment: You're replacing `</span>` by `</font>`, yet you're asking if pygments is generating the wrong output? It would seem that you do. Perhaps you need to remove those replacements, or add a replacement for `<span>` by `<font>` as well. Of course, that may not work if the opening tag is like `<span class="....`.

Comment: I didnt get you. Are you suggesting to make some code changes? I didnt manually generated that html. I guess its generated by pygments `PythonLexer` or `HtmlFormatter`. Are you suggesting to add / modify something to code?